# Getting results from a many-to-many relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I am trying to get results from a many-to-many relation (between users and roles) in a GraphQL resolver, but I'm quite new to Sequelize and don't understand the correct way to query the model.

Here is my user model:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var User = sequelize.define('users', {
 id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
 },
 name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
  allowNull: false
 },
 surname: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
  allowNull: false
 },
 email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
  allowNull: false
 }
}, {
 tableName: 'users',
 timestamps: false,
});

User.associate = function (models) {
 User.belongsToMany(models.roles, {as: 'UserRoles', through: 'users_roles', foreignKey: 'user_id'})
};

return User
};
```

Here is my Roles model:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Role = sequelize.define('roles', {
 id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
 },
 name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
  allowNull: false
 }
}, {
 tableName: 'roles',
 timestamps: false,
});

Role.associate = function (models) {
 Role.belongsToMany(models.users, {through: 'users_roles', foreignKey: 'role_id'})
};

return Role
};
```

And here is my join table model:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 return sequelize.define('users_roles', {
  id: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
   allowNull: false,
   primaryKey: true,
   autoIncrement: true
  },
  user_id: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
   allowNull: false,
   references: {
    model: 'users',
    key: 'id'
   }
  },
  role_id: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
   allowNull: false,
   references: {
    model: 'roles',
    key: 'id'
   }
  }
 }, {
  tableName: 'users_roles',
  timestamps: false
 });
};
```

This is, so far, my GraphQL definition:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express'
import * as db from '../database'

export const typeDefs = gql`
    extend type Query {
        users: [User]
        user(id: ID!): User
    }
    type User {
        id: ID!
        email: String
        name: String
        surname: String
        roles: [String]
    }
`

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        users: async () => db.users.findAll(),
        user: async (obj, args, context, info) => db.users.findByPk(args.id),
    },
    User: {
        roles: async (obj, args, context, info) => db.roles.findAll(), // wrong!!
    }
}
```

So basically my problem is that I don't get how I should write the query to get a list of all the roles that are assigned to one user.

What I would like to get in the end (as shown in the User type definition) is an array of strings containing all the role names.

Comment: Using `classMethods` has not been supported since version 3 and the latest release is already version 6. You should follow the [extensive documentation and examples available](https://sequelize.org/master/index.html) instead of following other tutorials, which may be outdated.

Comment: @DanielRearden as I said, I'm not that familiar with Sequelize. After extensive googling, it was looking like doing associations between models that are defined in various files seems to be complicated, as [this page](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4578) shows... I got the associate method solution from there.

Comment: @DanielRearden anyway, I have updated my code removing classMethods from users and roles (see the updated snippets in the question). I have checked with a console.log and the methods do actually get called.
Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `User` instance that we've correctly defined a `HasMany` or `BelongsToMany` relationship for with another model, we can get an array of the associated models by calling the appropriate method on our instance. The method name is normally `get[PLURAL_NAME_OF_MODEL]` (i.e. `getRoles`), but since you provided an `as` option to your relationship, the method should be `getUserRoles`. So it would be sufficient to just call:

```
return obj.getUserRoles()
```

Note that you can also [eager load](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#eager-loading-example) the associated model in your root resolver. In this case, you can omit the resolver for `roles` entirely if the `as` option matches your field name (i.e. as `roles`). If you eager load the associated models but the `as` doesn't match your field name (like in this case), then you can return `obj[WHATEVER_THE_AS_OPTION_IS]` (i.e. `obj.UserRoles`).

Edit: Since `roles` is a List of Strings and not objects, we need to do something like:

```
const roles = await obj.getUserRoles()
return roles.map(role => role.name)
```

Comment: I was of course aware that `db.roles.findByPk(obj.user_id)` was incorrect, hence the "wrong" comment right after it. It was just some placeholder code. I have replaced it with `db.users.getUserRoles()` and now what I get when I try do call the GraphQL query is this error: `_database__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.users.getUserRoles is not a function`

Comment: There is no static `getUserRoles` method. Just an instance method. You need to call it on an instance of `User`, which is what the first parameter of your resolver will be. Calling it on an instance will get the associated models for that particular instance.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I see the point. One more thing, if you please: how can I get just the array of names? I'm doing this `obj.getRoles({attributes: ['name']})` but getting the error `String cannot represent value: { dataValues: { name: \"Guitar\", users_roles: [users_roles] ` and so on

Comment: Oops, my bad. I was expecting `roles` to return a list of objects -- I didn't realize your schema had it typed as `[String]` instead. Please see my edit.

Comment: sorry to bug you once again... would it be somehow possible to do the two things you suggested (the eager loading and the map function) all in one go?
For now I've put the `obj.getUserRoles()` into its own resolver but this means of course a query on the roles table is executed for each user. But if I remove that and add for example `users: async () => db.users.findAll({include: db.roles})` I get an error again (of course because graphql expects an array of strings instead of an array of objects).

Comment: If you eager load, then what's passed to the resolver for `roles` will still be an instance of `User`, but that instance will have a property named `UserRoles`. So you can just access that, map over it and return the result. Alternatively, you could also apply this transformation when you fetch the users -- map over the users after they are fetched and for each one, create a `roles` property based on the `UserRoles` property.